# How do i create an sms gateway for my site with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sms, gateway

I would want to create an sms gateway to be sending sms to my site users with python, without using any sms gateway. how do i go about it.

I want it to be hosted in my site.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by SMS gateway but there is a Python module that allows you to send SMS messages .

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Clockwork/1.2.0

Basic example:

```
from clockwork import clockwork
api = clockwork.API('API_KEY_GOES_HERE')
message = clockwork.SMS(to = '441234123456', message = 'This is a test message.')
response = api.send(message)

if response.success:
   print (response.id)
else:
   print (response.error_code)
   print (response.error_message)
```

Sorry if this isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: What i meant is to send sms without any api

Comment: sms can be terminated to mobile from operators so you must use API of any [bulk sms service](https://www.springedge.com) provider. It can a HTTP or SMPP protocol call to mobile operator. In case you dont want to call API completely, You will need operator like setup/SMSC setup with huge cost.